# Formatting tabular layout with DT and DD

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why my formatting isn't great in this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/8k077vd5/1/)**. I'd like the titles to be aligned the same as the text on the right.

**HTML:**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Address</dt>
    <dd>Test <br />
Test <br />
Test</dd>

    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd>Test</dd>

    <dt>Fax</dt>
    <dd>Test</dd>

    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd><a href="mailto:">email@testtesttesttest.org</a></dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS:**

```
dl {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    dd {
    display: inline;

      &:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
      }
    }
}
dt {
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: broken fiddle, could u fix it pls

Comment: That's not plan CSS. What is that?

Comment: The Fiddle works for me, @AngularLover - http://jsfiddle.net/8k077vd5/1/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk you sure about that? looks like you're using SCSS or LESS but you still have the lang on the fiddle set to CSS.

Comment: @prodigitalson I've updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8k077vd5/2/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: inline-block` instead of `inline`: 
http://jsfiddle.net/x2bgfbwv/ *+ pink outline*

This would fix the allignment for your case.

Comment: Why is the pink box below 'Address'?

Comment: because of `outline: 1px solid pink;` - you can safely remove that property, its there for visualizing purpose only.

Comment: When I update, the text is still not aligned correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/x2bgfbwv/1/

Comment: i don't understand.. do you want something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/x2bgfbwv/6/ ?